# How do I prevent the automatic rounding of numbers in the Stimulsoft report?

Tags: c#, wpf, report, reporting, stimulsoft

I'm using the last version of Stimulsoft and C#. I have a report that gets data from SQL Server database and shows it.

My problem is that it rounds up without me adjusting it, like this :

```
123,456,789 => 123,456,792
```

My column in SQL Server:

[image]

in Stimulsoft:

[image]

What have I tried:

- using this Custom format: `#,0.##`
- using general or currency, instead of number
- using this expression:

```
{IIF(Floor(MyTable.Price)==MyTable.Price,Floor(MyTable.Price),MyTable.Price)}
```

None of them worked ...

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside Stimulsoft change type of Price column from float to decimal type.
then if you want set format
use this format type:
#,#0.#,#,#,#,#

Comment: Thanks I Changed it to decimal in Dictionary for Tables in Stimulsoft